# Using REST instead of database in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC app and need direction on where I should place my REST code. I am not needing to use a database because all of the data will be coming from and posting to a rest route that is external to my app. I am confused on where this layer should reside. Should I place my calls inside the controller class and create the necessary models for incoming/outgoing json objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your calls inside your controller classes directly but that would couple your controller classes to the external rest service. Or you could define an interface for the external service, implement it in a seperate class and use that class whenever it fits to your application.

Let's assume that the external service is about converting currencies, and the method you are using (for simplicity's sake) is called Convert. It takes three parameters, amount, fromCurreny and toCurrency.

Normally making a request to use this method involves giving an endpoint url, giving authentication information, giving parameter values in url and/or the request body. These are all unimportant details to your controller, it should not know about whether this is a GET request or a POST request. It doesn't need to know about the endpoint url. It doesn't need to know about the authentication information, it doesn't need to know about anything that is not directly about the method contract itself.

Which is something like this:

```
decimal convert(decimal amount, Currency fromCurrency, Currency toCurrency);
```

So you define an interface (a contract) that looks something like this:

```
public interface ICurrencyService
{
    decimal Convert(decimal amount, CurrencyDTO fromCurrency, CurrencyDTO toCurrency);
}
```

And you should implement it in a concrete class using your rest consumption logic:

```
public class YahooCurrencyService : ICurrencyService
{
    private string endpointUrl;
    private IYahooAuthenticator authenticator;

    public decimal Convert(decimal amount, CurrencyDTO fromCurrency, CurrencyDTO toCurrency)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClientOfYourChoice())
        {
            try
            {
                // Doing http work
                httpClient.PutHeaderValues(authenticator.GetHeaderValues());
                httpClient.Url = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}?amount={3}", endpointUrl, fromCurrency.Name, toCurrency.Name, amount);
                var response = httpClient.Get();
            }
            catch
            {
                // Exception handling
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can use it in your controller like:

```
private ICurrencyService currencyService;
```

...

```
var result = currencyService.Convert(amountFromUser, fromCurrencySelected, toCurrencySelected);
```

Now none of the entities in your system should know about the details they don't care about, and they are not coupled to other parts of your system. If you want to know more about S.O.L.I.D principles and it's motives you should go ahead and look it up. Uncle Bob Martin has good explanations on the topic and a lot of other experts too.

P.S: All of the codes above are fiction, you should make your own implementations.

Comment: That is great information and worked as I needed it too. I appreciate the time to help!

Comment: Glad I could help.